# Why did Remy show his chest when she asked him reason not to kill him?

Tags: plot-explanation, repo-men

In Repo Men (2010), Remy and Beth are running away from  Union's repo-men, suddenly they are pulled into a safe house by an unknown female who points her gun at Remy and asks him for a reason not to kill him. Then he lifts his shirt and shows his chest.

[image]

Is there any metaphor or pun behind this scene by showing the chest as a reason?

Comment: Damn, I was thinking "Repo Man" - an awesome off-beat movie with Emilio Estevez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are grabbed by artiforg refugees, who presume he is a repoman due to his tattoo. He shows them his chest, showing he is in fact running away from  repomen as well, and that he is an artiforg refugee as well.